# txjsonrpc server with a requests client

Tags: python, twisted

Trying to contact a `txjsonrpc` server from a `requests.post()` request.

**Server**

```
from txjsonrpc.web import jsonrpc
from twisted.web import server
from twisted.internet import reactor


class JsonRpc(jsonrpc.JSONRPC):
    def jsonrpc_status(self):
        return {"status": "200"}

reactor.listenTCP(interface="127.0.0.1", port=7081, factory=server.Site(JsonRpc()))
reactor.run()
```

**Client**

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:7081 -d '{"params": [], "method": "status"}'
>>> '{"status": 200}'
```

This works.

The python library `requests` does not:

**Client #2**

```
import requests

req = requests.post(
    url="http://127.0.0.1:7081",
    data={
        "params": [],
        "method": "status"
    })

print req.status_code
>>> 500
```

Server spews out an error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
exceptions.ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

The parameters for `requests.post(data)` are correct in the client #2 example. However If I look at the ngrep output I can see that `params` is being discarded.

**CSI:ngrep**

```
bla@bla:$ sudo ngrep -qt -W byline port 7081
interface: eth0 (192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0)
filter: (ip or ip6) and ( port 7081 )

T 2015/08/30 16:03:18.202439 192.168.1.30:41272 -> 192.168.1.61:7081 [AP]
POST / HTTP/1.1.
Host: 192.168.1.61:7081.
Content-Length: 13.
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress.
Accept: */*.
User-Agent: Mozilla 4.3.
.
method=status
```

As you can see, only method=status is transferred. `requests` decides that my `params` parameter is not worth sending because it is empty. This creates an exception on the txjsonrpc server.

How can I contact `txjsonrpc` server with a `requests` client request?

Also; I don't mind switching to another jsonrpc server library that is compatible with Twisted if that will make my life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also notice your POST from `requests` is not sending JSON as your `curl -d` is, it's sending x-www-form-urlencoded key/value pairs. Try replacing `data=` with `json=` in your `requests.post` call, as shown in [this example](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).